# Unable to delete virtual machines image and storage

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

Unable to delete virtual machines image and storage.

I was trying to delete the virtual machine image and get the  "Initial Server Error" error message.
Then I entered the storage of the image. Then the page keep redirect me to following

> You are seeing this message because we cannot determine if your
>   account must comply with the requirements of the Federal Information
>   Security Management Act (FISMA). You are accessing an information
>   system that may contain U.S. Government data. System usage may be
>   monitored, recorded, and subject to audit. Unauthorized use of the
>   system is prohibited and may be subject to criminal and civil
>   penalties. Use of the system indicates consent to monitoring and
>   recording. Administrative personnel remotely accessing the Microsoft
>   Azure environment
>
> 1) Shall maintain their remote computer in a secure
>   manner, in accordance with organizational security policies and
>   procedures as defined in Microsoft Remote Connectivity Security
>   Policies.
>
> 2) Shall only access the Microsoft Azure environment in
>   execution of operational, deployment and support responsibilities
>   using only administrative applications or tools directly related to
>   performing these responsibilities and
>
> 3) Shall not store, transfer
>   into, or process in the Microsoft Azure environment data exceeding a
>   FIPS 199 Moderate security categorization (FISMA Controlled
>   Unclassified Information)

[Here is an image with this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYGHv.jpg)

Firstly, there is no government data in my image, the storage of the image is automatically created by wizard when I created the image.
I have tried it again over several days, it just never allow me to delete.
In addition, it just keep draining out my Azure credit.  I am not sure what I should do to delete this image and its storage.
Please give me some advise. Thanks.